# MongoDB : projection matches all element corresponding to query

Tags: mongodb

Supposing the following data format

```
{
  _id: "1234",
  tag: "MyTag",
  members: [{
    name: "James", age: 54
  }, {
    name: "John", age: 22
  }, {
    name: "Eric", age: 36
  }],
},
{
  _id: "7896",
  tag: "MyTag2",
  members: [{
    name: "Philip", age: 6
  }, {
    name: "Mark", age: 14
  }, {
    name: "Maya", age: 64
  }],
}
```

How can I request all the person over 30 to get that result

```
{
  _id: "1234",
  tag: "MyTag",
  members: [{
    name: "James", age: 54
  }, {
    name: "Eric", age: 36
  }],
},
{
  _id: "7896",
  tag: "MyTag2",
  members: [{
    name: "Maya", age: 64
  }],
}
```

Basically this request

```
db.MyDB.find({'members':{'$elemMatch':{'age':{'$gt':30}}}}, {'tag:1', 'members.$':1})
```

but where the **.$** operator does not return only the first or each list

(I'm using python api but I think the question applies more generally)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positional operator `$` and the `$elemMatch` projection operator both only match the first element that matches the query.

If you want to get all elements that match, use aggregation and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html#filter-aggregation) the array.